# Javascript alert is making webpage to get struck

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am using below code to alert users about the timings of the restaurant. The code works fine in the desktop browsers but in mobile chrome browser when it needs to alert it struck the webpage. When it doesn't need to alerts webpage loads smoothly.

```
window.onload=startTime(); 
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    if(h >= 22 || h < 11)
    {
    alert("Restaurant Re-opens at 11 AM. You can still Place Order Now.");
    }

}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
        }  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

How to solve this????

Comment: Did you tested in desktop chrome browser?

Comment: yeah,it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are always syncrhonous, they will ALWAYS block the code execution until you click ok, which is useful if you're debugging, but on production, everything will stop until you click ok.

Don't use native alerts, you could use an UI plugin that shows a message to the user, either a [bootstrap alert](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2415206/42416876-4532c09a-827a-11e8-89b6-a8cf263d4db0.png), or a [jQuery alert](https://www.jquery-az.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/22.0_2-jQuery-alert-jAlert-basic.png).

Learn about DHTML and frameworks (vuejs and so), it looks like all you know is vanilla js, so you have a long way ahead of you.

If you don't want to use an entire framework to solve this issue, I'd recommend that instead of alerting the user, conditionally write to the document that orders won't be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timed modal which will disappear after, say 2 seconds, and the next page will load smoothly